# SSRS 2008 - get data based on row number

Tags: ssrs-2008

I need to create a report with a collection of gauges. The data coming into the report is structured like:

```
Client  Specialty    TrendsPercent

ABC     Hematology   33.2 
ABC     Urgent Care  30
DEF     Psychiatry   80
DEF     Pulmonary    59
DEF     Neurology    12
```

The number of rows for each client, as well as the specialties listed, is variable.  What I've been trying to do is create a 5x5 grid of gauges. Each row in the original data will be a gauge.  So:

```
Row1Gauge | Row2Gauge | Row3Gauge | Row4Gauge | Row5Gauge
Row6Gauge | Row7Gauge | Row8Gauge | Row9Gauge | Row10Gauge
```

etc.

The problem I've been running into is how do I reference one specific row's data based solely on the row number?  There are too many gauges to just have one column in a tablix object, I need to have the gauges 5 wide at least.  I've tried filtering a tablix based on the `RowNumber` but SSRS doesn't allow that.  Any ideas on how I could go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out a work around for this.  While you can't filter a tablix based on row number you CAN set visibility based on it.  So, I have 5 tablixes side by side and I'm setting the visibility on the first one to show for rows 1, 6, 11, 16, 21.  The tablix next to it is only showing rows 2, 7, 12, 17, 22, etc.  I don't know how this is going to affect the performance when the report is used on the sharepoint site, but I know of no other way of going about this.